# How do I get image url of attribute option in Magento?

Tags: image, magento, attributes

How do I get an image URL of an attribute option in Magento?

For example, we have attribute 'manufacturer' with options LG, Philips etc.
Attribute options in Magento have a personal field for an image.
I want to use that image as the logo of the manufacturer.
How do I display that image on the product page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clarify - are you talking about Attributes (configured at admin panel: Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes) or about Custom Options (configured at admin panel: Catalog -> Manage Products -> *select product* -> Custom Options)?

Both do not have personal field for an image. That is why your question is quite confusing. Is it possible, that you have some custom extension installed, which provides that image functionality? If it is true, then you need to contact the extension's author, because only the author knows a proper method to use.

Just some references for your information:

- You can check [this tutorial and free custom extension](http://www.johannreinke.com/en/2012/02/05/magento-add-images-to-product-attribute-options/), which
  adds images to the dropdown Attributes. It displays images at
  frontend.
- You can check [this solution at MagentoCommerce.com public forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/223960/), which will help 
  you to add images to Custom Options.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
It is in Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes.
I see. I have installed gomage advanced navigation.
Any help?

Comment: Each extension has its own models and interfaces. You should contact author or try to figure out it yourself.